# Postgres "Like" Keyword

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a temporary table in postgres by copying the column names and types from an existing table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE grades;
```

Typing the query into Postgre, it tells me about an error in LIKE. Is "Like" keyword not usable in Postgre or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the like statement in parentheses:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table (LIKE grades);
```

If you want defaults or indexes included as well, you need to add that explicitly

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table 
    (LIKE grades INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
```